# Unity - change API level

Tags: unity, api

I tried uploading a game to google play. But I got a warning that the API level needs to be changed to a diferent one. I'm not sure how to do that in Unity as I had not configured it before. Can someone please help. I have attached a screenshot of the warning.[image: APIwarning]

Answer (score 2):

This question doesn't demonstrate research effort. Searching Unity Android API Level will lead you to [the documentation for Android Player Settings](https://docs.unity3d.com/2020.1/Documentation/Manual/class-PlayerSettingsAndroid.html#Identification), including:

> **Minimum API Level** Minimum Android version (API level) required to run the application.
>
> **Target API Level**  Target Android version (API level) against which to compile the application.

Here you'll find a drop-down to select your target API level:

[image: Screenshot of Unity project settings in older version on Windows]

[image: Screenshot of Unity project settings in newer version on Mac]

Answer (score 1):

Open [Android Studio -> SDK Manager -> Android SDK -> SDK Platforms] and download Android 10.0 (Q)

Make sure that in PlayerSettings (Ctrl+Shift+B -> Player Settigns) Target API Level is `Automatic (highest installed`.

[image: SDK Manager]

[image: SDK Platforms]